# Remember previous keys?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
function read(a) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
    if (!key) {
        return {}
    } else if (!key.includes(";")) {
        var inkey = a[key];
        delete a[key]
        return read(Object.assign({}, inkey, a))
    } else {
        console.log(key)
        delete a[key]
        return read(a);
    }
}

var locations = {
    "buildings":{
        "3;":{"name":"Market"},
        "8;":{"name":"Free car"},
        "9;":{"name":"House"}
    },
    "people":{
        "males":{
            "16;":{
                "name":"John",
                "items":{
                    "food":1,
                    "water":1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
read(locations);
```

The function `read(locations)` does as expected and prints every number.

How would I go about to find what is closest to a set number including the previous keys.

For example: If the closest thing to a number is "John" (number 16), I also need that the object is in "males" & "people", not just everything "in" the number.

I could use a similar function to `read()` to get whatever is "after" the number (so that being name and items if it exists) though I want to remember the previous keys.

Comment: please add the relevant missing code as well, and some examples of input and wanted output, maybe you have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: @NinaScholz There is no missing code? I added `read(locations)` and changed coordinates to numbers and the `spot` function to a `console.log` for your viewing pleasure - but the code is exactly the same.

Comment: where do you check for closeness?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable for the path to the object.

```js
function read(a, path) {
    if (!a || typeof a !== 'object') {
        return {};
    }
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key.includes(";")) {
            console.log(key, path.join(', '));
            return read(a[key], path || []);
        }
        read(a[key], (path || []).concat(key));
    });
}

var locations = { buildings: { "3;": { name: "Market" }, "8;": { name: "Free car" }, "9;": { name: "House" } }, people: { males: { "16;": { name: "John", items: { food: 1, water: 1 } } } } };

read(locations);
```